# How to use nodejs to separate contents of file divided by double newline?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What Im trying to do:
1. Read the file
2. Split the read file.

Here is a sample input file -

```
#This is a comment

Line one of first block,
Line two of first block,
Line three of first block.


Line one of second block.
Line two of second block
line three of second block.

Line one of third block.
```

Each block is separated by newlines ( no control over whether they would be windows/unix).
How to go about using getting each block read separately using nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use split() function.

```
var blocks = str.split([separator],[limit]);
```

After this you may try to iterate the array like

```
blocks.each(function(err, block) {
    console.log(block);
});
```

However, you should check, what to specify as separator - Windows or UNIX (CRLF or just LF).

Comment: Tx. I have no control over the seperators. Does split take two values for seperators?

Comment: actually, <separator> is a simple regexp, you may use smth like /^\r\n||\n$/i or just /\r\n|\n/

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript split to do that. same code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qrc3R/2/). Will work even there is white space between new line character.

```
 // assuming content is your text.
    var contentArray = content.split(/\n\s{0,}\n/);
```